# ngxpermissions not working with child component

Tags: javascript, angular, permissions

I am using ngxpermisions to load a button that renders child component

```
<dx-button *ngxPermissionsOnly="['ROLE_GEN_ADMIN','ROLE_LOCAL_ADMIN']" icon="add" type="normal" text="Add" style="margin-left: auto;" (onClick)="add()">
            </dx-button>
            <app-add ></app-add>
```

How to do this. Right now the button is not appearing. It appears once i remove the child component

Comment: Please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz where the issue happens!